# Unity - How to create octaves in procedural terrain?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, procedural-generation

I'm making procedural terrain generation for my Unity game, and I want to add octaves to my terrain to make it look more like in the image. How would I go about doing this?

[image: Image is right here]

Here is my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[RequireComponent(typeof(MeshFilter))]
public class MapGenerator : MonoBehaviour
{

    Mesh mesh;

    Vector3[] vertices;
    int[] triangles;

    public int xSize = 20;
    public int zSize = 20;

    void Start()
    {
        mesh = new Mesh();
        GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh = mesh;    

        CreateShape();
        UpdateMesh();
    }

    void CreateShape()
    {
        vertices = new Vector3[(xSize + 1) * (zSize + 1)];

        for (int i = 0, z = 0; z <= zSize; z++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x <= xSize; x++)
            {
                float y = Mathf.PerlinNoise(x * .3f, z * .3f) * 2f;
                vertices[i] = new Vector3(x, y, z);
                
                i++;
            }
        }

        triangles = new int[xSize * zSize * 6];

        int vert = 0;
        int tris = 0;

         for (int z = 0; z < zSize; z++)
         {
            for (int x = 0; x < xSize; x++) 
            {
                triangles[tris + 0] = vert + 0;
                triangles[tris + 1] = vert + xSize + 1;
                triangles[tris + 2] = vert + 1;
                triangles[tris + 3] = vert + 1;
                triangles[tris + 4] = vert + xSize + 1;
                triangles[tris + 5] = vert + xSize + 2;

                vert++;
                tris += 6;
            }

            vert++;
         }
    }

    void UpdateMesh()
    {
        mesh.Clear();

        mesh.vertices = vertices;
        mesh.triangles = triangles;

        mesh.RecalculateNormals();
    }
}
```

I tried this code below, but it looked more like spikes than a landscape. I would use this tutorial [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wbpMiKiSKm8&list=PLFt_AvWsXl0eBW2EiBtl_sxmDtSgZBxB3) if I were even able understand it at all.

```
float[] octaveFrequencies=new float() {1,1.5f,2,2.5f} ;
float[] octaveAmplitudes=new float() {1,0.9f,0.7f,0.f} ;
float y=0;
for(int i=0;i<octaveFrequencies.Length;i++)
 y += octaveAmplitudes[i]* Mathf.PerlinNoise(
      octaveFrequencies[i]*x + .3f, 
      octaveFrequencies[i]* z + .3f) * 2f ;
```

Comment: This is not really a technical programming problem, mostly a functional problem to your application. Also not enough information is given to allow others to contribute in my opinion.  You reference an information source from a other person but no link provided...

Comment: @Schwarzie2478 I just updated with a link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you are implementing this code correctly. It seems like your amplitudes are pretty high. I find that a frequency that doubles each iteration and an amplitude that halves each generation looks nice. The values you choose depend on what kind of terrain you want.

```
float[] octaveFrequencies=new float() {1,2f,4f,8f} ;
float[] octaveAmplitudes=new float() {1,5f,0.25f,0.125f} ;
```

Try using these values. These are the settings I commonly use. If you want different-looking terrain, try to change them around a little bit. Changing these values can drastically change the look of the terrain.

Alternatively, you could do this automatically:

```
const int numOctaves = 4;
float y = 0;
float frequency = 1;
float amplitude = 1;
const float frequencyMult = 2f;
const float amplitudeMult = 0.5f;
for(int i = 0; i < numOctaves; i++) {
    y += Mathf.PerlinNoise(x * frequency, z * frequency) * amplitude;
    frequency *= frequencyMult;
    amplitude *= amplitudeMult;
}
```

This code does the same thing as before, except you can arbitrarily set the amount of octaves. Increasing the numOctaves increases the detail. Higher frequencyMult increases detail at the cost of smooth terrain, and higher amplitudeMult increases the influence of the detail at the cost of smooth terrain. Change the constants to get a different result. To change the max height, just multiply "y" after this loop.
Some variables and syntax might be wrong, because I just typed this up.

If you haven't noticed, the frequency increases exponentially and the amplitude decreases exponentially. If you decrease amplitude linearly, then there might be too much influence on detail, causing large spikes. Also, if you increase frequency linearly, then similar frequencies will add up, causing the same high hills and valleys.

Comment: I don't know why but every time my script runs your code it will make the entire mesh flat

Comment: Can you show me your implementation? Send me the entire function please.

Comment: [Here you go](https://pastebin.com/5CJtfK87)

Comment: PerlinNoise is the same value at integer coordinates, so offsetting it or scaling it to make the value fractional could also fix that problem. With your original code you already did that when you multiplied "x" and "z" by 0.3f. This made it so x and z were almost always fractional, allowing for different results.

Comment: [Here is my CreateShape function](https://pastebin.com/cwdH6pZT) and yes I'm sure it's completely flat

Comment: Paste this line into your start function and tell me what it logs: "Debug.Log(CreateOctaves(1, 1));"

Comment: it prints out 0.872387

Comment: Use this line instead: "y += Mathf.PerlinNoise(x * 1.1f * frequency+ 0.12f, z * 1.1f * frequency + 0.12f) * amplitude;". The problem is 100% the bug I describe. Using Integers with PerlinNoise always returns "0.4652731". When you do the math, the amplitudes, when each multiplied by that value and added together, equal "0.872387". By using the line above, the problem should be fixed.

Comment: Actually, I had the same problem before, and it took me a while to figure it out. It's really annoying that Unity doesn't address this problem in the docs. The only way I can think of to completely remove this problem is to just use your own implementation of a Noise function, like 2D Simplex Noise.

Comment: definitely looks a lot better but how would I make it look more like a landscape than how it looks right now?

Comment: also do you know what was used to make the mesh look like the one in the image above?

Comment: Can I see what it looks like right now for reference? You can change how it looks by changing the frequencyMult and amplitudeMult. You can change the scale by multiplying the x and z coords before you put them through the CreateOctaves function: "CreateOctaves(x * scale, z * scale);". The smaller the scale the wider hills are. You can also multiply CreateOctaves function by some value to increase the max height: "CreateOctaves(x * scale, z * scale) * maxHeight;".

Comment: Okay  [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1vlAOrgKreiOg7W3P13W8gxzRZMn44Us-?usp=sharing) is what it looks like right now

Comment: I'd say, set the scale to around 0.1f, and set the maxHeight to around 2-5, depending on what looks best. Make sure you have shadows on, too.

Comment: okay it looks way better but just one more question is there a way I could make it look more like [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dcbljvqu-eTovhq9Gt95ld7fDbVlwXI3/view?usp=share_link) while using my same code and without having to do a bunch of complex calculations and stuff like that?

Comment: Depends on the complexity. That image is from Sebastian Lague's video, right? You should be able to follow his series at that point. The color of the terrain requires some type of custom shader or something, I don't remember exactly. There is like an array of colors in the mesh that corresponds with the vertices. If you implement the shader, then you just have to edit the array. Just watch his tutorial at that point (You should also probably watch the videos before too bc I think he explains each part.)

Comment: Okay I will do just that

Comment: After researching, the array is called mesh.colors. Each element corresponds with each vertex, in the same order. ([link](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mesh-colors.html)). You will still have to implement Sebastian's Custom Shader, so watch that part of the video.

Comment: I actually have been following Sebastion's tutorial and my terrain is almost exactly what I wanted thanks for the suggestion